# include certificates in .OVPN file

Tags: openvpn

I have tried to create an VPN server of my own.  I have `ca.crt`, `server.crt`, and `client.key`.  How can I combine these into a single .opvn file?

Will it work if i change the extension of `server.crt` to `server.ovpn`?

Comment: `server.ovpn` isn't the certificate...it's the configuration file...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Assuming you don't actually mean to "convert", but to "combine", "embed" or simply "use".*

You can use the `[inline]` directive inside your **.ovpn** config file.
There's a good example here: [Embedding key/cert/ca into client config](http://web.archive.org/web/20160629033150/http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.network.openvpn.user/32469)

```
ca       [inline]
cert     [inline]
key      [inline]
tls-auth [inline] 1

<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
# insert base64 blob from ca.crt
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>

<cert>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
# insert base64 blob from client1.crt
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</cert>

<key>
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
# insert base64 blob from client1.key
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
</key>

<tls-auth>
-----BEGIN OpenVPN Static key V1-----
# insert ta.key
-----END OpenVPN Static key V1-----
</tls-auth>
```

Comment: thanks for your link it helped me ..i have pasted my client crt and client key and do i wanna save that i .ovpn file format ??

Comment: do i wanna save that file in .ovpn format ??

Comment: You can give the resulting file any extension you want, it's your party. `.ovpn` or `.conf` are common.

Comment: if i save it in  .ovpn it can be used by openvpn right ??

Comment: Again, it doesn't matter. OpenVPN doesn't care about the file extension, it only cares about the contents.

Comment: @AvinashBabu It's worth noting that you will need to have the regular openvpn client configuration directives as well, whether you choose to embed certificates in that same file or have them as separate files is entirely up to you.  See eg https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#client

Comment: @Jorn but openvpn loads only .ovpn files ??

Comment: @jornane it depends on the client.  My android client complains if the file does not end in .opvn  (which is a pain since newer versions won't let you transfer files named that in using common file transfer methods).    The popular TunnelBlick client on Mac's add config dialog asks you to double-click the file and have OS feed it to OpenVPN.   Only .opvn is registered with the OS.  Clicking a file named myconfig.txt will open the text editor instead.  So, yeah, the file extension is important in many case.

Comment: I meant .ovpn in my earlier, no longer editable comment.

Comment: sadly, the link in this answer is no longer available.

Comment: @szeitlin Thanks! I've updated the answer